# In React, state is not being updated properly when concatenating individual input state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seven different input fields and updating the state with the entered value. After that, I am concatenating all the state values and updating the contractNum state but it is not being updated correctly. It is missing the first state (this.state.contact.sys) value. I am not sure how to get the right concatenated value. Any help is much appreciated.

```
export default class test extends Component {
  state = {
    contact: {
      sys: '',
      co: '',
      lgr: '',
      mgr: '',
      sub: '',
      serial: '',
      num: ''
    },
    contractNum: ''
  };

  test = testValue => {
    this.setState({
      contractNum: testValue
    });
  };

  handleChangeFor = propertyName => event => {
    const { contact } = this.state;
    const newContact = {
      ...contact,
      [propertyName]: event.target.value
    };
    this.setState({ contact: newContact });
    let newValue =
      contact.sub +
      contact.co +
      contact.mgr +
      contact.lgr +
      contact.sub +
      contact.serial +
      contact.num;
    this.test(newValue);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="container">
          <form>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChangeFor('sys')}
              value={this.state.contact.sys}
              maxLength={2}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChangeFor('co')}
              value={this.state.contact.co}
              maxLength={1}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChangeFor('mgr')}
              value={this.state.contact.mgr}
              maxLength={1}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChangeFor('lgr')}
              value={this.state.contact.lgr}
              maxLength={1}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChangeFor('serial')}
              value={this.state.contact.serial}
              maxLength={6}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChangeFor('num')}
              value={this.state.contact.num}
              maxLength={2}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChangeFor('sub')}
              value={this.state.contact.sub}
              maxLength={1}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `contact.sub` instead of `contact.sys` when setting `newValue`.

Comment: Thank you for answering!! I changed sub to sys but contractNum is not updating the last value. For e.g, if I enter 1 to 7 in seven input fields, then contractNum has 123456 value in the state. Last entered value is missing. Why is it so?

Comment: State doesn’t update immediately - so every time you set newValue using “contact.property” - that value hasn’t been updated in state yet. You could use newContact directly.